# Why we cannot attribute the length to probability in this example?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I've started a book called "Probability Essentials" and in the first chapters, just before defining a Borel set, it gives an example that is not clear for me at all:

[Page 35](https://i.stack.imgur.com/miBa3.jpg)

My question is that why the suggested scheme doesn't work? Intuitively, it seems so reasonable.

I'd really appreciate gentle instructions to the solution as I don't have a solid measure theory background.

Comment: Using this scheme, we can deduce the probability of a lot of sets (for example, because $[a,b]$ and $]a,b]$ have the same probability, we can deduce that $\{a\}$ has probability $0$. And using the union property any countable set should have probability $0$). But the problem is that there exists sets that cannot be constructed from intervals by using intersections and countable unions (so your scheme doesn't say anything about them). Constructing such a set is not obvious; it requires a bit of work and is usually part of measure theory courses.

Comment: @JoelCohen can you give an example of such sets?

Comment: the construction is quite technical. You can find it on Wikipedia : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_set

Comment: You might find the article is a bit difficult without any background in measure theory, so my advice would be to trust for now that such sets exist, until you can come back to it later when you have more familiarity with the topic.